# getting: "unable to handle kernel paging request" when trying to read

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, paging

I trying to pass data from the kernel space to the user space and all I see is 'killed' in the console, and when I try to look at `dmesg` I see:
`unable to handle kernel paging request`

My kernel module init function:

```
static int __init module_init_function(void) {

    struct file_operations fops = {
        .owner = THIS_MODULE
    };

    struct class *m_c;
    struct device *dev;
    DEVICE_ATTR(fw_dev, 0777, show_func, store_func);

    /* Create the user interface device */

    major = register_chrdev(0, "fw_status", &fops);
    m_c = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "fw_class");
    dev = device_create(m_c, NULL, MKDEV(major, 0), NULL, "fw_dev");
    device_create_file(dev, &dev_attr_fw_dev);

    return 0;

}
```

And here is my show function:

```
static ssize_t show_func(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf) {

    return snprintf(buf,PAGE_SIZE, "%d,%d", accepted_packets, dropped_packets);

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEVICE_ATTR` macro creates a `device_attribute` [in the scope it's called.](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/device.h#L539) Since it's in your init function, that `device_attribute` is lost after the module is initialized. (On a sidenote, it would still be deleted even if it was static inside init function. Since your init function has `__init`, the function will be purged from memory after module initialization)

Try calling `DEVICE_ATTR` globally.

Same goes for `file_operations`, it should also be global. Kernel stores them as a pointer and does not copy the entire structure, so that you can modify it later.

You can browse [kernel source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=DEVICE_ATTR) to see how other modules are implemented. A quick search reveals that `DEVICE_ATTR` is always used globally.

Also, you probably do not need `snprintf(9)`, `"%d,%d"` will not exceed buf's size anyway.

Comment: @Algosub haha I've answered your 3 questions today, admins here might think we're working together to farm reputation :D

Comment: haha... Thank you so much! it's homework for my degree and we got almost 0 explanations about what I asked...

Comment: @Algosub been there :) kernel is hard to begin without reading a few books. I recommend Linux Device Drivers book by the way, it's like a kernel bible, great place to start, it has many examples.